# Ansible: playbook not running with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, python-venv

I have cloned ansible repository and setup following official ansible documentation.

I have setup from source directly, by creating `venv` for python3.

Running this: `. venv/bin/activate && . hacking/env-setup` does set up ansible environment. And if I write this (while `venv` is activated):

```
ansible-playbook --version
```

It outputs this:

```
ansible-playbook 2.8.5.post0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/oerp/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/oerp/src/ansible/lib/ansible
  executable location = /home/oerp/src/ansible/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.7 (default, Mar 29 2019, 10:38:28) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

So it does show that it used Python version `3.6.7`. And if I run unittests for my custom modules that have python `3.6` syntax, tests run fine (tests are run with `tox` as documented by ansible itself).

But it fails to run my module via playbook. And it looks like it is executing it using python2.

When I run this command:

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "target=local_stage" --connection=local /home/oerp/src/ansible-playbooks/buildout_test.yml -vvv
```

It throws this traceback:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oerp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570781848.1110492-2720137190388/AnsiballZ_focusate_buildout.py", line 114, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "/home/oerp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570781848.1110492-2720137190388/AnsiballZ_focusate_buildout.py", line 106, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "/home/oerp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570781848.1110492-2720137190388/AnsiballZ_focusate_buildout.py", line 49, in invoke_module
    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
  File "/tmp/ansible_focusate_buildout_payload_JDfOK3/__main__.py", line 52
    path: str,
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Clearly it does not recognize typing syntax. Looking at debug, I can see such binaries being executed:

```
<stage-my-domain.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/oerp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570781848.1110492-2720137190388/AnsiballZ_my_buildout.py && sleep 0'
```

In my environment `/usr/bin/python --version`, is `Python 2.7.12`

Debugging also shows this information:

```
<stage-my-domain.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.7'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.6'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.5'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python2.7'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python2.6'"'"'; command -v '"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'; command -v '"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'
```

Does anyone know why ansible ignores activated `venv` and just use global python which is python2?

P.S. I also have ansible installed globally via `apt-get install ansible`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

venv is a bit tricky to use. It is tied to your session. Ansible uses a different session when gets executed than you as a user who logs in. You need to activate venv for that specific session that Ansible uses when gets executed.

You can try two things:

1: setting environment variables:

```
environment:
  PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/yourpython/bin"
  SOME: value
```

2: setting the Ansible python interpreter

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-python-not-having-a-python-interpreter-at-usr-bin-python-on-a-remote-machine

> Setting the inventory variable ansible_python_interpreter on any host
>   will tell Ansible to auto-replace the Python interpreter with that
>   value instead. Thus, you can point to any Python you want on the
>   system if /usr/bin/python on your system does not point to a
>   compatible Python interpreter.
>
> Some platforms may only have Python 3 installed by default. If it is
>   not installed as /usr/bin/python, you will need to configure the path
>   to the interpreter via ansible_python_interpreter. Although most core
>   modules will work with Python 3, there may be some special purpose
>   ones which do not or you may encounter a bug in an edge case. As a
>   temporary workaround you can install Python 2 on the managed host and
>   configure Ansible to use that Python via ansible_python_interpreter.

Comment: If I understood correctly, it is important what python is used for target environment, not the one ansible itself is run from (like which python to use on some remote server). Though I did not see any mention of this in documentation, where it explains how to setup environment and then use it.

Comment: Exactly. I know it a bit hard to see how this works but essentially Ansible will create a Python file that will be copied to the target host and it will be run there with the target host Python. I think this might not be called out in the documentation. You can do a debug run to see what happens. -vvv and it will print out what is going on.